# set data in Javascript multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created this multidimensional array in javascript.

```
var arr = [];
arr[0] = [];
arr[0][0] = [];
arr[0][0][0] = [];
arr[0][0][0][0] = [];
```

and assigning values to the using this code

```
arr[0] = 1;
arr[0][0] = 2;
arr[0][0][0] = 3;
arr[0][0][0][0] = 4;
arr[0][0][0][0][0] = 5;
alert("arr ==> " + arr);
```

But it gives output as only `1`, but the desired output is `1,2,3,4,5`

When I do this `alert(arr[0][0]);` the desired output is `2` but it gives `undefined`.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have multi-dimentional arrays in the manner you're thinking. It has nested arrays just like you can have nested objects (since arrays are just objects).

Comment: Even if your "multi-dimensional array" *was* filled the way you intended, it would never print `1,2,3,4,5`. That being said, JavaScript is not PHP. Chances are you are using the wrong data structure.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks for replying. Can you tell me how can I set the data in my desired manner.

Comment: As has been said, there are no true multi-dimensional arrays in JavaScript, only nested arrays. Can you tell me what you want to do? (*"I'm trying to use a multi-dimensional array"* is not an answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overwriting your values:

```
arr[0] = [];
...
arr[0] = 1; // this also blows away arr[0][0], arr[0][0][0], etc
```

so...

```
arr[0][0] = 1;
==
1[0] = 1;
```

What *exactly* are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to set the values at zero position upto 5 dimension.

Comment: You can't have `arr[0]` be both zero and an array.  What's the purpose of this?

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [];
arr[4] = [];

arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 2;
arr[2] = 3;
arr[3] = 4;
arr[4] = 5;

alert("arr ==> " + arr );
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Alerts as

```
arr ==> 1,2,3,4,5
```